# Eclipse per project build setting

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way in Eclipse to set up `Project>Build Project` or `Project>Build Automatically` in a project by project case? Normally these settings are referring to all the projects of the current workspace. The closer I could get is `Preferences>Workspace>Build Order` but then again this is referring to the order of the builds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it is not possible by design. I quote from [an older discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=3033#c7) about the same subject:

"we decided that a mode with autobuild on a subset of the workspace confused the notion of autobuild, which currently implies that the user needs to know nothing about builds.  Our
thinking is that a new working set build, for which you can add a key binding
(or remap Ctrl+B), is close enough for the small group of users that want this
capability."

So I guess that is your best bet.

Comment: thanks. I'll be trying the Ctrl+B remap then to fit my needs.