# How do I stop the m2eclipse plugin interfering with command line mvn builds?

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse

I use the m2eclipse plugin in Eclipse so that I can import a Maven project. The plugin reads the pom.xml and sorts out the dependencies in the projects in an Eclipse friendly way so I'm not looking at a sea of broken references and errors.

I use Eclipse for code development however I usually build the projects from the command line, e.g. "mvn clean install".

Unfortunately when I do this, m2eclipse detects disk activity and attempts to rebuild the workspace. This interferes with the command line build and sometimes results in a race condition. For example the command line might be in its clean phase but fails because it tries to delete a file or directory which is locked during the workspace rebuild. Aside from that workspace rebuilding is incredibly slow, and between failed builds and wasted CPU my build process is 2-3x longer than it should be.

It isn't an option to not use Eclipse (e.g. to use Netbeans), or to disable m2eclipse. It is a useful plugin except for this behaviour.

So my question is, how do I stop m2eclipse from rebuilding the workspace all the time? Can I invoke a manual refresh and otherwise disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fix, you could deactivate automated Eclipse builds unticking `Project > Build Automatically`

Comment: It's not building the project, it's rebuilding the workspace. i.e. it sees some changes in the project folder and m2eclipse kicks off a mvn build of some kind to update the workspace to reflect the changes.

Comment: This option is for the whole workspace actually. There isn't a way in Eclipse to build automatically per project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333672/eclipse-per-project-build-setting Have you tried it?

Comment: Disabling auto build seems to have done it. I still see blips where the status bar says rebuilding workspace but the actual invocation seems to be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *Eclipse* detects that the compiled resources are gone and starts rebuilding.

You should not need to perform `mvn clean install` , but rather `mvn install`, as all your resources are already up-to-date.

Comment: The plugin does a workspace rebuild even when I do a "mvn install"

Comment: Well, it depends on your pom as well. Can you post it? Otherwise, you should report a bug towards M2Eclipse : https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what dimitrisli said, I would suggest using different output directories for eclipse and command line.

You do this by defining a new profile (ex. "eclipse") and set the output directory to be `<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes-eclipse</outputDirectory>` in that profile.

That way even if you build in parallel (from eclipse and from command line) they won't interfere with each other.