# How do I configure project-specific 'Build automatically' setting in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I need automatic build in some projects that I work on, but I also project with JDK code that I imported for research, and I don't want to build that automatically at all.
How can I configure Eclipse to fit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a project, from the Project menu you can select or deselect build automatically.

Comment: Thanks, never thought it was that obvious.

Comment: This only works for all projects, not for specific projects - at least with Indigo.

Comment: This is not *per-project* but again the same *global* setting. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4335314/483588